# Display the content posted in users city automatically based on IP Address of user in a Page

Tags: php, drupal

It should display the contents posted automatically based on the city in which user is browsing the Web site. I am trying to use SmartIP. I am trying to use the following code:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code'] == 'IN'):
?>
```

India content specific

```
<?php
elseif ($_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code'] == 'UY'):
?>
```

Uruguay HTML content specific

```
<?php
....
else:
?>
```

Fallback default content.

```
<?php
 ...
endif;
?>
```

I tried to use the country code as 'IN'. But it is not displaying the content. I am trying to change the code as

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code']['state_code'][city_code] == 'BAN'):
?>
```

My Doubt is :

How can I display the content posted in Bangalore automatically, if the user is browsing from the city say Bangalore or Delhi etc... ?
Where can I add these country, state, city codes?

Comment: From reading the question above it soes not get clear what your setup is. What url is called? Where is that php code kept? How does your html template look like? It is hard to try to give an anser if the setup is hazy.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the display of content so that a user may only see content tagged with their location? Or do you just want to give your users the option to see content specific only to their location?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to implement a 'dictionary function': you call it with the geographic code you mention and it returns the localized content you want to embed in the html template. In background it consults a 'catalog', that typically is an array structure like this:

```
$LCat = array (
  'India' => array (
    'Assam' => array (
      'Dispur' => "some Dispur specific content",
      'Guwahati' => "some Guwahati specific content",
      ... some other cities in that state ...
    ),
    'Orissa' => array (
      'Bhubaneswar' => "some Bhubaneswar specific content",
      ... some other cities in that state ...
    ),
    ... some other states in that country ...
  ),
  ... some other countries ...
);
```

The function looks for a matchin entry in the catalog (e.g. by using the is_set() function):

```
if ( is_set($LCat[$_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code']]) ) {
  if ( is_set($LCat[$_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code']['state_code']]) )
    if ( is_set($LCat[$_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code']['state_code']['city_code']]) ) ) {
      $Location=$LCat[$_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code']['state_code']]['city_code']];
    } else {
      $Location=$LCat[$_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code']['state_code']]
  } else {
    $Location=$LCat[$_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code']]
} else {
  $Location="location specific content for 'Nirwana'";
}
```

So the structure is: state > country > city, or whatever structure you require. The idea is: try to use the most specific match in the catalog. If it is not present, then use the entry a little less specific and so on. This way you always have a safe fallback coded in the structure instead of having to code fallbacks for every location your script might stumble upon.

Obviously the content stored for a match can be anything, I only chose simple strings to make the point. Also the structure could be stored in a different way, for example in a file system hierarchy you examine at runtime, a folder for each country, in that a folder for each state, in there files for each city or the like. If you want to improve performance and offer an easy way to manage the catalog data then you sould store that catalog in a database which you query at runtime. The idea remains the same, though.

Note that I have not tested that code, but it should give you a suggestion of a possible approach.

Comment: I am able to display the city based on IP address and able to post specific text based on city. I have created taxonomy terms for cities. I want  to display posts posted in taxonomy terms. Ex: If, user is browsing from delhi, the posts using term delhi should be displayed. how to achieve it?

Comment: Well, what is the problem with that? Have you tried anything? What? What exactly is the question you cannot answer yourself? Obviously the posts must be stored somewhere, it makes sense to use a database for that. Next, when you want to extract posts that contain a certain string (here:delhi) you query that database for all posts that contain the string 'delhi'. Something like this: `SELECT id,user,message FROM posts WHERE message LIKE '%delhi%';`. It probably also makes sense to use some random number to display different posts each time, or to order them by age or something.